# spl_autoload_register couldn't get "use" namespace

Tags: php

```
#file1
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once "{$class}.php";
});

new classes\Foo();

#file2
namespace classes;
class Foo implements toolInterface {
    function __construct(){
        echo __CLASS__; 
    }

    public function tool(){

    }
}
```

I have a problem with spl_autoload_register, above example works fine, but when I try to use `use classes` it will have fatal error, anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
//fatal error
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once "{$class}.php";
});

use classes;
new Foo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ability to refer to an external fully qualified name with an alias
>
> Note that for namespaced names (fully qualified namespace names
> containing namespace separator, such as Foo\Bar as opposed to global
> names that do not, such as FooBar), the leading backslash is
> unnecessary and not recommended, **as import names must be fully
> qualified, and are not processed relative to the current namespace**.

[PHP: Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

So we need the fully qualified name

```
use classes\Foo;
new Foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you log the `$class` variable provided to the closure you have you'll note that the FQCN (Fully Qualified Class Name) is given. In your case:

```
classes\Foo
```

You will need to ensure the file path is correct for that.

Or you could also use the de-facto standard - [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) - Don't mind the fact that the home page has a picture of a conductor.